# Add text to Folium map using an absolute position

Tags: python, folium

I have defined in my Python program:

```
fig = Figure(width, height)
map = folium.Map(location=[y, x], zoom_start=2)
fig.add_child(map)
```

How can I add text to my map using absolute position (not latitude/longitude one) ?
A position defined by a percentage of the width and the height of the Figure.
Something like

```
Text("Toto is my name", pos_x=0.1*width,pos_y=0.05*height)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here my solution.
FloatImage do the job for an image ...
so I have decided to convert my text into png and then use this method

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
W, H = (300,200)
im = Image.new("RGBA",(W,H))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
msg = "pycoa.fr (data from: {})".format(mypandas.data_base)
w, h = draw.textsize(msg)
fnt = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf', 14)
draw.text((0,0), msg, font=fnt,fill=(0, 0, 0))
im.crop((0, 0,2*w,2*h)).save("pycoatextlogo.png", "PNG")
FloatImage("pycoatextlogo.png", bottom=0, left=0).add_to(map)
```

It is not perfect, but it works :) [image]

Answer (score 10):

I've looked into it and it doesn't seem to have that feature, as long as you have the x,y coordinates you can easily annotate the text. I've customized it by referring to [this page](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/BibMartin/ec2a96034043a7d5035b) and [this page](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/340).

```
from folium.features import DivIcon
import folium

m = folium.Map([34.0302, -118.2352], zoom_start=13)
folium.map.Marker(
    [34.0302, -118.2352],
    icon=DivIcon(
        icon_size=(250,36),
        icon_anchor=(0,0),
        html='<div style="font-size: 20pt">Toto is my name</div>',
        )
    ).add_to(m)
m
```

[image]