# Add counter to Folium map of markers that meet a specific condition

Tags: python, html, maps, dashboard, folium

I work for a small ISP and have written a script to collect data from the switches that is then fed into Folium to produce a map of subscribers and their operating status as online of offline.

I need to add a counter, maybe through a div, that would allow for markers of any status to be counted and displayed in the window like the top left corner.

The cluster option in Folium has helped to give an idea for areas but i would like an overall total as well that is easily seen without the need for adding cluster totals.

Does Folium have something like this that i've just missed or is there another python based dashboard that i could create the number with and add it as a div somewhere.

I've looked at some python based dashboards but most of those are heavily graph based. I really only need a square box with a number that changes based on the total number of markers/subscribers that are offline.

Comment: Does this new plug-in fit your use case? https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/TagFilterButton.ipynb It was just added so you would have to install from te main branch. It shows the total number in a small square in the top left, you could probably style that a bit.

Comment: @Conengmo thanks for adding this, it doesn't quite fit what i was looking for but is still something i could implement for other use cases. For this number i want something more prominently displayed on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description of how to add text or images to folium maps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65105474/13843906

text will be moving with the map, but image seems to be at a fixed position in map window